# change proxy instantly C#

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy

I have a problem, I want to change the proxy of my browser every time I can, but it does not change until after a while or I check to see if the ip was changed in the internet options, this is the code

```
        reg_key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SoftWare\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
        string proxy = txtIp.Text + ":" + txtPort.Text;
        reg_key.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
        reg_key.SetValue("ProxyServer", proxy);
        MessageBox.Show("IP cambiada, ", proxy);

        cronometro.Start();
        timer1.Start();
        label5.Text = (100 - cronometro.Elapsed.Seconds).ToString();
    }
```

Now, How can I make it change instantly?

Answer (score 0):

When using Selenium you can (and should) set the Proxy information when creating the WebDriver using the `Proxy` property on the `InternetExplorerOptions`, `FirefoxOptions`, or `ChromeOptions` objects used when creating the WebDriver.